# Pandas DataFrame constructor not properly called in web scraping

Tags: pandas, get, request

#What is the problem with this code?

```
from pandas import DataFrame

import pandas as pd

import requests


p = 'https://www.codal.ir/Company.aspx?Symbol=اخابر'

r = requests.get(p, verify=False)

t = str(r.text)

df = pd.DataFrame(t)
```

I want to read the website data above
But I had a problem converting data to data frame
Please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### `read_html`

And it returns a list, so pluck off the first element

```
p = 'https://www.codal.ir/Company.aspx?Symbol=اخابر'
r = requests.get(p, verify=False)
t = str(r.text)
df = pd.read_html(t)[0]

df.iloc[:5, :5]

                  0              1                  2      3        4
0               NaN            NaN                NaN    NaN      NaN
1               NaN            NaN                NaN    NaN      NaN
2        نام شرکت :  مخابرات ايران             نماد :  اخابر  Akhaber
3               NaN            NaN                NaN    NaN      NaN
4  سرمایه ثبت شده :       60000000  سرمایه ثبت نشده :      0        0
```